# Replace groupByKey() with reduceByKey()

Tags: scala, apache-spark, machine-learning, mapreduce, distributed-computing

This is a follow up question from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35373478/mapping-of-elements-gone-bad). I am trying to implement k-means based on this [implementation](http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~rxin/ampcamp-ecnu/machine-learning-with-spark.html). It works great, *but* I would like to replace `groupByKey()` with `reduceByKey()`, but I am not sure how (I am not worried about performance now). Here is the relevant minified code:

```
val data = sc.textFile("dense.txt").map(
        t => (t.split("#")(0), parseVector(t.split("#")(1)))).cache()

val read_mean_centroids = sc.textFile("centroids.txt").map(
        t => (t.split("#")(0), parseVector(t.split("#")(1))))
var centroids = read_mean_centroids.takeSample(false, K, 42).map(x => x._2)
do {
    var closest = read_mean_centroids.map(p => (closestPoint(p._2, centroids), p._2))
    var pointsGroup = closest.groupByKey() // <-- THE VICTIM :)
    var newCentroids = pointsGroup.mapValues(ps => average(ps.toSeq)).collectAsMap()
    ..
```

Notice that `println(newCentroids)` will give:

> Map(23 -> (-6.269305E-4, -0.0011746404, -4.08004E-5), 8 -> (-5.108732E-4, 7.336348E-4, -3.707591E-4), 17 -> (-0.0016383086, -0.0016974678, 1.45..

and `println(closest)`:

> MapPartitionsRDD[6] at map at kmeans.scala:75

Relevant question: [Using reduceByKey in Apache Spark (Scala)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24071560/using-reducebykey-in-apache-spark-scala).

---

Some [documentation](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions):

> def reduceByKey(func: (V, V) ⇒ V): RDD[(K, V)]

Merge the values for each key using an associative reduce function.

> def reduceByKey(func: (V, V) ⇒ V, numPartitions: Int): RDD[(K, V)]

Merge the values for each key using an associative reduce function.

> def reduceByKey(partitioner: Partitioner, func: (V, V) ⇒ V): RDD[(K, V)]

Merge the values for each key using an associative reduce function.

> def groupByKey(): RDD[(K, Iterable[V])]

Group the values for each key in the RDD into a single sequence.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use an `aggregateByKey()` (a bit more natural than `reduceByKey()`) like this to compute `newCentroids`:

```
val newCentroids = closest.aggregateByKey((Vector.zeros(dim), 0L))(
  (agg, v) => (agg._1 += v, agg._2 + 1L),
  (agg1, agg2) => (agg1._1 += agg2._1, agg1._2 + agg2._2)
).mapValues(agg => agg._1/agg._2).collectAsMap
```

For this to work you will need to compute the dimensionality of your data, i.e. `dim`, but you only need to do this once. You could probably use something like `val dim = data.first._2.length`.

Comment: Worked like a charm! Can you explain what we did here? I mean why would I want to replace groupByKey() with reduceByKey()? What is the main advantage of doing that? Relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24804619/how-does-spark-aggregate-function-aggregatebykey-work

Comment: Well, the `groupByKey` is going to cause a bunch of stuff to be sent around between the various nodes, i.e. all the values associated with a given key, for all keys and parts of the data. With the 'aggregateByKey' approach, on the other hand, each part is only responsible for transmitting (to the driver) a pair consisting of the sum and count. So much less network communication as well as obviating the need to create all those collections of values (since it is only their sum and count that matter in computing the average.)